# Split comma and one by one value show on android

Tags: java, android, split

```
String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25"; 
Double.parseDouble(model.getEcg1().split(",") + "\n")
```

This is not working.
I want the result like below i.e. value one by one column wise:

```
10
20
100
-100
20
10
110
-105
15
25
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? what is your output?

Comment: I think you missed something here. can please let me know what is "model.getEcg1().split(",")".

Answer (score 0):

`split` will create a **array** of `String`, and not a single `String`, so you can't parse it to `Double`. After splitting the `ecg1`, you can iterate through the list and print it.

```
try {
    String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25";
    String[] items = ecg1.split(",");
    ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(items[i]));
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can do anything you want with the list of double numbers. `Double.parseDouble` can throw exception so that you should catch it.

If you just want to generate a string which values are displayed as a column, there will be a simpler solution

```
String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25";
String result = ecg1.replace(",", "\n");
```

Comment: Since when does a string split return a List instead of an array?

Comment: Thank you. my code is                                                                                                 
           protected List<DataEntry> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            List<DataEntry> seriesData = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < arrayList.size(); index++) {
                ChartModelEcg model = arrayList.get(index);

Comment: @uneq95 I'm using Kotlin, sorry

Comment: datas are coming from sqlite database

Comment: Set set = Set.instantiate();
            set.data(seriesData);
            Mapping series1Mapping = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value'}");

Comment: I mean how do you print the result as column, not getting data

Comment: Cursor cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * from table_sensor_readings where fd_sensor_id='" + model.getSensorId() + "'  order by fd_auto_id desc,fd_incr desc", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                                                             
                                                                                                                     
            String ecg1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fd_ecg1"));

Answer (score 0):

```
String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25";
String[] ecg2=ecg1.split(",");
```

then you can iterate through ecg2 with a normal loop

```
for(int i=0;i<ecg2.length;i++)
{
//ecg2[i] is the element you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 you just can do

```
String str = String.join("\n", ecg1.split(','));
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the given string into String Array and then insert the items by parsing into Double data type Like in the code given below:-

```
String[] items = ecg1.split(",");
ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(items[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as `model.getEcg1().split(",")` will return a string array.
You can not parse whole string array to double by this `Double.parseDouble(model.getEcg1().split(","))` and adding `\n`is again not going to work.

if you only want the desired output to print you can try this below code

```
String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25";
    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(ecg1.split(","));
    stream.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

if you want to store in Collection do as below

```
String ecg1 = "10,20,100,-100,20,10,110,-105,15,25";
    List<Double> li=new ArrayList<>();
    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(ecg1.split(","));
    stream.forEach(x -> li.add(Double.parseDouble(x)));
```